# sys v shared memory from kernel module to user space process

Tags: linux-kernel, ipc, shared-memory, kernel-module, sysv-ipc

i am new in linux kernel module developpement and i am searching for sharing a memory segment from kernel module to user space process to escape latency of copying data.

i am using the sys v shared memory api, when i share memory between two process it's work fine, but i am not able to share memory between process and kernel module.

bellow is my code of the kernel module and the user space app

server side : module

```
#include <linux/module.h> // init_module, cleanup_module //
#include <linux/kernel.h> // KERN_INFO //
#include <linux/types.h> // uint64_t //
#include <linux/kthread.h> // kthread_run, kthread_stop //
#include <linux/delay.h> // msleep_interruptible //
#include <linux/syscalls.h> // sys_shmget //

#define BUFSIZE 100
#define SHMSZ BUFSIZE*sizeof(char)
key_t KEY = 5678;

static struct task_struct *shm_task = NULL;


static char *shm = NULL;
static int shmid;

static int run_thread( void *data )
{
    char strAux[BUFSIZE];
    shmid = sys_shmget(KEY, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if( shmid < 0 )
    {
        printk( KERN_INFO "SERVER : Unable to obtain shmid\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    shm = sys_shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if( !shm )
    {
        printk( KERN_INFO "SERVER : Unable to attach to memory\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    strncpy( strAux, "hello world from kernel module", BUFSIZE );
    memcpy(shm, strAux, BUFSIZE);
    return 0;
}

int init_module()
{
    printk( KERN_INFO "SERVER : Initializing shm_server\n" );
    shm_task = kthread_run( run_thread, NULL, "shm_server" );
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    int result;
    printk( KERN_INFO "SERVER : Cleaning up shm_server\n" );
    result = kthread_stop( shm_task );
    if( result < 0 )
    {
        printk( KERN_INFO "SERVER : Unable to stop shm_task\n" );
    }
    result = sys_shmctl( shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL );
    if( result < 0 )
    {
        printk( KERN_INFO
        "SERVER : Unable to remove shared memory from system\n" );
    }

}


MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL" );
MODULE_AUTHOR( " MBA" );
MODULE_DESCRIPTION( "Shared memory  server" );
```

client side : process

```
#include <sys/ipc.h> // IPC_CREAT, ftok //
#include <sys/shm.h> // shmget, ... //
#include <sys/sem.h> // semget, semop //
#include <stdio.h> // printf //
#include <string.h> // strcpy //
#include <stdint.h> // uint64_t //

#define BUFSIZE 4096
key_t KEY = 5678;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int shmid, result;
    char *shm = NULL;

    shmid = shmget(KEY, BUFSIZE, 0666);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(-1);
    }
    shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (!shm) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", shm);
    result = shmdt(shm);
    if (result < 0) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

any suggestion or document can help.

Comment: And what is printed by kernel module and user space app?

Comment: when i am trying to insert the module .ko i get the erro : (-1) unknown symbol that refer to sys_shmhet, sys_shmat.., but the compilation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System calls are not intended for being use by the kernel: they are for user programs only. Also, it is unlikely that is sys v memory sharing works for kernel threads.

Kernel and kernel modules have their own mechanism for interract with user 
space. For sharing memory, your kernel module may implement character device and `mmap` method for it, which maps kernel's allocated memory to user. See example of such `mmap` implementation in *Linux Device Drivers*(3d edition), Chapter 15.

Comment: This [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1mNXXw6TNAhWJOBoKHTxgBK4QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.145.6401%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNGh8qSDajUD0bPt0nbtM2PvQM5ikA&sig2=TttseQSxvpZB1i7oC1lA5Q) present 3 method of fast data transfer between kernel thread and user space app, one of those 3 method is sys v shared memory !!!

Comment: The article explicitely tells, that you need to **modify kernel** for make sys v shared memory works: `Exporting the kernel functions *sys_shmget*, *sys_semget* ... was nessesary to allow kernel module to create and destroy SYS V Shared Memory regions...` (at the end of page 16).