# share memory between kernel and user space using sys v

Tags: shared-memory, kernel-module, userspace, sysv-ipc

i see that is so easy to share memory segment between user space process using sys v api (`shmget(), shmat(), shmdt()` ), is there any solution to use the same api to share memory from kernel to user space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think thant's no way to do that without modifying kenel files, look at this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682266/sys-v-shared-memory-from-kernel-module-to-user-space-process), i am refering to this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1mNXXw6TNAhWJOBoKHTxgBK4QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.145.6401%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNGh8qSDajUD0bPt0nbtM2PvQM5ikA&sig2=TttseQSxvpZB1i7oC1lA5Q)